# Xml text extracting python

Tags: xml, python-2.7, parsing, xpath, lxml

This is the API URl -

```
https://api.dynadot.com/api3.xml?key=26T8F9U8t8Fj6e8m6172p80849H8GN8i6m8O7U7pC7u&command=search&domain0=000.com
```

When i make a Http request using

```
requests.get('https://api.dynadot.com/api3.xml?key=26T8F9U8t8Fj6e8m6172p80849H8GN8i6m8O7U7pC7u&command=search&domain0=000.com')
```

I get XML response : -

```
<Results><SearchResponse><SearchHeader><SuccessCode>0</SuccessCode><DomainName>000.com</DomainName><Status>success</Status><Available>no</Available></SearchHeader></SearchResponse></Results>
```

I would like to extract each elements , How can i do that , I dont want to use regex library . I was trying with lxml library but its not working : -

```
url = 'https://api.dynadot.com/api3.xml?key=26T8F9U8t8Fj6e8m6172p80849H8GN8i6m8O7U7pC7u&command=search&domain0='+each1
r = requests.get(url)
print r.text
source = html.fromstring(r.content)
available = source.xpath('/available/text()')
print available
print "For %s availability is %r" %(each1, available)
```

Anybody please help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that XML and also XPath are *case-sensitive*, so *'available'* is never the same as *'Available'* in this context.

Another thing to fix is the single slash at the beginning of your XPath. Replace it with double-slashes (short notation for `descendant-or-self` axis) like so  `//Available/text()`, or use a full-path from the root to the target element `/Results/SearchResponse/SearchHeader/Available/text()`.

**Full working demo example :**

```
from lxml import etree

content = '''<Results>
   <SearchResponse>
      <SearchHeader>
         <SuccessCode>0</SuccessCode>
         <DomainName>000.com</DomainName>
         <Status>success</Status>
         <Available>no</Available>
      </SearchHeader>
   </SearchResponse>
</Results>'''
source = etree.fromstring(content)
available = source.xpath('//Available/text()')
print(available)
```

**output :**

```
['no']
```

Comment: It worked . Thanks.. But whats the difference between html.fromstring & etree.fromstring ?